# find complete image path in php?

Tags: php

i have a serialized string like this :

[image]

now i want to find the image information from this string and then store it in a variable. i can find the image path and it prints from below code

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($stry);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");
echo $src;
```

but i want to print the complete `img` tag with atrributes like height , width etc in below form :

```
$a = "<img src=\"http://www.techveze.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Router.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"345\" height=\"120\" class=\"aligncenter size-full wp-image-1884\" />" ;
```

anyone plz help me...??

thanx.

Comment: The answer here might help you: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/18465

Comment: Sure you'll need to unserialize the string first

Comment: i have the unserialize string too.. but in that string the image shows like an icon not as a path so i can not get it from there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unserialize the string. This will return an array. The image is stored in the index `image`.

```
// Unserialize the string and turn it into an array
$array = unserialize($str);
$a = $array['image']; // This will give you image with the enclosing `<a>` tag

// Create a document from the HTML snippet
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($a);

// Obtain the image tag
$img = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);

// Save it as string
$img_string = $doc->saveHTML($img);
```

If you want to display the string in a HTML page, I mean the string not the image(!), then use `htmlentities()`:

```
// Echo the <img> as string(!) on an HTML page
echo htmlentities($img_string);
```

Comment: what i actually want to do is to extract the full image path and then stores it in the database... but here the index shows the icon of image not the actual path

Comment: it gives the error :  Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::parseHTML() in C:\wamp\www\meta.php on line 103